# How can I create a AVD for tablet testing?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I can I create a AVD for android 4.0.3 so that I can test my app on emulator?
I have download android 4.0.3 SDK from Android SDK manager. But how can I create a AVD so that i will run as an tablet environment? The only one I found is SamSung Galaxy Tab, but that is for API 8. I am looking for something which works on 4.0.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check How to Test Your Application on Multiple Screens
in fallowing link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

its given there how can you test your app on tablet.
you just have to change your avd according to extra large. 
remember one thing skin for tablet is available from 3.0 .

In 4.0 skin for tablet is not there.
for that try 3.0 to 3.2 versions( which were made for tablets specifically. \

Android avd sucks,

I suggest, use genymotion its fast. faster then your phone

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a skinned version of the Samsung Galaxy Tab, it is currently not available for any of the ICS API levels.

And using just the resolution to create Tablet emulator for ICS can be slightly tricky. For example, the Samsung Galaxy S II has a resolution of 720 * 1280 pixels.

To create an AVD for a tablet based on the ICS API, you should use the "**WXGA800**" from the drop down under the "Skin" option. I used this very option to create a tablet AVD and use it all the time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

in skin: where you select between built-in or resolution check in built-in drop down if WXGA720 or WXGA800 exists, if any of two are there then select one and create avd in the case of 4.0 it creates tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you start eclipse.

Click in the menubar [Window -> AVD Manager]

Click 'New' to create a new emulator.

Here you can select which target/platform you want to run on it.
And select the resolution for the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can create any size/resolutions of AVD. Just define the resolutions while creating AVD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see, there is no specific device emulator for 4.0.3. you can just create an avd from device manager with the api level 15 as the previous answer says. doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are 7 year old now and eclipse specific.

The current solution using Android Studio described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) is:

1. open Android Studio
2. Go to Tools -> AVD Manager
3. Click + Create Virtual Device